# brightspace/d2l Is there an API to get all CanSelfRegister courses

Tags: desire2learn, valence

We have some courses that can be self-enrolled. I can locate them via individually if I know their org unit code: `/d2l/api/lp/1.29/courses/<orgUnitId>` and can see that the "CanSelfRegister" attribute is correctly set.

We also have a page within d2l itself, `<baseurl>/d2l/lms/legacy/selfregistration.d2l?ou=<orgUnitId>` which displays a list of all courses that students can self-register for.

Is there an API which I can call to efficiently locate all courses with the CanSelfRegister attribute = true? I hoped it might be something like `/d2l/api/lp/1.29/orgstructure/<parentId>/descentants/?CanSelfRegister=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no such route via the API.